# Error in t-test: not enough x-observations

Tags: r, na, t-test

I am having issues computing a t-test.
First some background info: I am trying to compare the values of males and females, and in order to run the t-test I first had to create single-variables for only the male values and only the female values, which I did like this:

```
occupation_attr_m <- filter(ds, sex == "male")  %>% pull(occupation_attr)
occupation_attr_m

occupation_attr_f <- filter(ds, sex == "female")  %>% pull(occupation_attr)
occupation_attr_f
```

Howvever, now when I try to compute my t-test I get the error that there arent enough x-observations. What can I do? There are quite a few NAs in the variables I created above, and I tried to get rid of them by adding the "na.rm = TRUE" to the t-test, but that didnt help.

Here is how I tried to calculate my t-test:

```
H5b <- t.test(as.numeric(ds$occupation_attr_f), as.numeric(ds$occupation_attr_m), na.rm = TRUE)
H5b
```

Thank you very much in advance for any advice!!

Comment: If you look at the source for `stats:::t.test.default` (which is what you're using), that error message comes up twice (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/t.test.R#L60 and https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/t.test.R#L72), both relying on the length of `x` and `y`. (1) Check your `occupation_attr_*` variables and find the one that is length 0 or 1, that is a culprit; (2) look at `ds` to make sure that the case/spelling within `sex` values is correct, perhaps it is actually camel-case or something else (`==` is case-sensitive).

Comment: If that doesn't clear it up, please provide some representative sample data, perhaps `df %>% group_by(sex) %>% head(3) %>% select(sex, occupation_attr) %>% dput(.)` (intending to get a few of both but no more data than we really need). (The use of `dput` is important, as it reveals ambiguities that normal console output may hide (such as `factor`s).